# C initialize const struct member with existing const variable

Tags: c, struct, constants

I'm using default C under gcc.

My code:

```
typedef struct _OpcodeEntry OpcodeEntry;
```

//

```
struct _OpcodeEntry
{
    unsigned char uOpcode;
    OpcodeMetadata pMetadata;
};
```

//

```
const OpcodeMetadata omCopyBytes1 = { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, &CopyBytes };

const OpcodeEntry pOpcodeTable[] =
{
    { 0x0, omCopyBytes1 },
};
```

Errors:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for 'pOpcodeTable[0].pMetadata')
```

If I change `omCopyBytes1` to what it's actually set to in the above line, the code compiles fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `omCopyBytes1` to initialize a member of `pOpcodeTable[]` array, because `omCopyBytes1` is a variable that is run-time constant, not a compile-time constant. Aggregate initializers in C must be compile-time constants, that's why the code from your post does not compile.

As a variable, `omCopyBytes1` has its own place in memory, which is initialized to an array of items. You can use such variable by a pointer, like this:

```
struct _OpcodeEntry {
    unsigned char uOpcode;
    const OpcodeMetadata *pMetadata;
};
...
const OpcodeEntry pOpcodeTable[] = {
    { 0x0, &omCopyBytes1 }, // This should work
};
```

Alternatively, you can make it a preprocessor constant:

```
#define omCopyBytes1 { 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, &CopyBytes }
```

If defined in this way, the `omCopyBytes1` would no longer be a variable: it would be a preprocessor definition that vanishes before the compiler is done. I would recommend against the preprocessor method, but it's there in case you must do it.

Comment: Are constant expressions really required to initialize all aggregates in C99?  I don't see anything in section 6.7.8 of the C99 standard saying so (other than for objects of static storage duration).

Answer (score 0):

In C, initializers for objects of static storage duration must be *constant expressions*. A `const`-qualified variable is not a constant expression.

Comment: Surely you don't mean *all* initializers must be constant expressions, unless you're claiming that something like `int x = rand();` is illegal.